# Are there any studies on marked adjective order in the NP in head initial languages like Spanish or Albanian?

Tags: syntax, pragmatics, adjectives

For example, Spanish unmarked NP order is Noun-Adjective ("libro rojo", "casa grande"). However, there are many situations where the order is reversed ("un rojo atardecer", "es un buen libro", "tienes un lindo perro"). I'd like to read any studies on this topic to understand the reason why. It doesn't need to be about Spanish and, in fact, I'd prefer if it weren't exclusively about Spanish (ideally it would be about general patterns, but I'd still be alright with studies concerning individual languages).

Answer (score -1):

This may be something like what you’re looking for?

https://doi.org/10.1353/lan.2018.0054

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Based on the freely available first page, this does not seem like it has anything to do with what the question is asking about.